# meta tags do not work on indes

Tags: html, tags, meta

all sites work fine, exept the index page. the meta does not work, non of it shows well in google neither the title of the page.

I do not understand what could be the issue..

```
<!doctype html>

<head>


    <!-- meta -->


<title>Open Minded Life Path - How to change your life</title>
<meta name="description" content="A collection of positve thinking and how to change           life-guides. The best life changing solutions and tested self motivation techniques. ">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Positive thinking, How to change your life, how  to change, how to start  new life, how to change yourself, life changing solutions, unclutter, free thinking, life changes, positive approach, lifestyle, positive thinking, self motivation techniques, what is a life coach">
  <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting  the html tag under doctype You need to have a html tag.

Comment: The start tag for the HTML element is optional.